# Disabling TLS1.0 in mod_proxy

Tags: apache, ssl, jboss, mod-proxy

We are using apache http server 2.2.29 and jboss 6.4. 
We are using Mod proxy for communication between web server and jboss application server.

We are planning to disable TLSv1.0 in mod proxy configuration. After disabling tlsv1.0, the mod_proxy's ssl configuration looks like below.

```
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
    SSLCertificateFile /app/certificates/star_rpmi.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /app/certificates/rpmi.key
    SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile /app/jboss.keystore
    SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1
```

However, once we disable the tlsv1.0, the communication between mod proxy and jboss application server fails.

In apache's debug logs, we have found that the ciphers suits being negotiated is `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384`

This cipher suit have been added in jboss application server configuration file as well. However, the connection is still failing.

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: Still failing how? And why do you need SSL between your reverse proxy and your application server? Normally they are in the same LAN.

Comment: yes, still failing. That's what I am trying to figure out.